# Adding location of start and end points to the attribute table

Tags: qgis

I want to add start and end points to my attribute table for each feature in one layer in terms of actual location and not distance form start meter i.e. start being 0 and end point 10 meters. Is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the expressions

`start_point($geometry)` and `end_point($geometry)`

This expression alone will result in `NULL` in your attribute table. To make it readable in your attribute table combine it with `geom_to_wkt()` or `x()` and `y()`. For example:

- `geom_to_wkt(start_point($geometry))` (Use `Text (string)` as field type) or
- `x(start_point($geometry)) || ', ' || y(start_point($geometry))` (Use `Text (string)` as field type)
- `x(start_point($geometry))` (Use `Decimal number (real)` as field type)

Enter the expression in your field calculator and make sure to set `output field type` correctly as well as `ouput field length` and `precision`:

[image]

Comment: It seems to not work with both expressions as NULL appears with both expression types

Comment: And make sure to choose the correct output field type, e.g. `Text (string)` for WKT or concatenated coordinates.

Comment: How do you make sure its the correct output field?